# React js css loader gives an failed to compile issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My css is not working and it gives an error of failed to compile and it says can't  resolve the image

error image

[image]

new error image
[image]

Comment: You image's path might be broken, check your devtool to verify image is loading or not.

Comment: path is not broken can you please help me

Comment: Then I guess next step will be to post your css here. Also, what setup are you running on? Have you forgotten to add an appropriate loader for .png-files?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS file is not able to find the asset (the image) it needs. Remove that line in the CSS file where your asset is set as the source or add it in the src/assets folder.

Comment: ı did that removed the image codes from the css but ı got this new error